# How to add a legend manually by ggplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a task I have to make a plot with ggplots with a correct legend.
Well my plot is good, but my legend is not as I want.
I want in my legend a specifing that the triangle is for Sepal, and the plus for Petal.
Can someone help me?

[image]

Below is my script.

```
ggplot(data=iris)+
  geom_point(aes(x  = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color=group), shape=2)+
  geom_point(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color=group), shape=3)+
  xlab("lengte (cm)")+
  ylab("breedte (cm)")+
  theme(legend.justification=c("left","top"))
```

Comment: Add `shape="Sepal"` to the `aes()` for the first points and `shape="Petal"` to the `aes()` for the second points and then you can add to the plot: `scale_shape_manual(values=c(2,3))`

Comment: Thankyou, but I still have an error

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a `group` variable, but here is an example:

```
iris$group <- as.factor(sample(c(0,1), nrow(iris), replace=TRUE))
ggplot(data=iris)+
  geom_point(aes(x  = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color=group, shape="Sepal"))+
  geom_point(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color=group, shape="Petal"))+
  xlab("lengte (cm)")+
  ylab("breedte (cm)")+
  theme(legend.justification=c("left","top"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(2,3))
```

[image]